# Defining array of enum type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have created a Typescript DTO, where I want to ensure type safety for a list of strings (which are derived from an enum type.

```js
export class ConnectedUserWithPhotosDTO extends UserWithPhotosDTO {
  userTags: keyof User["userTags"][]

  constructor(user: User, photos: ResponsePhotoDTO[]) {
    super(user, photos)
    console.log(user.userTags)
    this.userTags = user.userTags;
  }
}
```

The typescript compiler complains about the following error:

`Type 'UserTags[]' is not assignable to type 'number | keyof UserTags[][]'.`

apparently, the value of `userTags` evaluates to

```
number | keyof UserTags[][]
```

Here is the enum definition that i am defining.

```js
export enum UserTags {
  FITNESS = 'Fitness',
  FOURTWENTY_FRIENDLY = '420 Friendly',
  MEDITATION = 'Meditation',
  DRINKS = 'Drinks',
  DOGS = 'Dogs',
  CATS = 'Cats',
  FASHION = 'Fashion',
  WINE_TASTING = 'Wine Tasting',
  FOODIE = 'Foodie',
  ART = 'Art',
  PARTYING = 'Partying',
  TRAVELIING = 'Travelling',
  GAMING = 'Gaming',
}
```

Inside the User class the `UserTags` is defined as:

```
 @ApiProperty({ enum: UserTags, isArray: true, default: [] })
  @Column('enum', { enum: UserTags, array: true, nullable: true, default: [] })
  userTags: UserTags[]
```

how can I define just the type of `keyof` for the specific Enum value?

Comment: Provide the `User` type. It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm 99% sure that you just want the string enums and want `userTags: UserTags[]`, but I'll explain in an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do something like:

`const userTags: User['userTags'];`

Comment: How does the compiler know if it a single instance or a list?

Comment: @Ating it just uses the exact same type of the `userTags` property in the `User` type.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that UserTags is enum. Its something like

```
userTags: Array<keyof typeof UserTags>
```

Comment: Problem is that `UserTags` is a nested attribute on the User Class

Comment: Provide user class definition, please

Comment: Your answer is what they asked for - the keys of the enum object.  But I don't think it's what they actually want.  They are obviously confused, but I think they want the enum values `Array<UserTags>`.

Answer (score 1):

Your post is a bit confusing because of your use of `keyof`.  It's unclear whether you want the enum *keys* `"FITNESS"`, etc. or the enum *values* `"Fitness"`, etc.

It's clear based on the code of the `User` and your error message that what you are *getting* when you access `user.userTags` is the *values*.  The type of the values is just the enum itself, so you would want

```
userTags: UserTags[]
```

just like what you have in the `User`.  It makes sense that this would match the type in `User` since we are setting the `userTags` property based on `User["userTags"]`.

---

Let's break down the type `keyof User["userTags"][]` that you tried and see what it really means.

`User["userTags"]` gives us the `userTags` property of the `User` type.  We can see from your `User` code that `User["userTags"]` is `UserTags[]`.  That is an array of the values from the `UserTags` enum.  So something like `["Fitness", "Fashion"]`.

`User["userTags"][]` means that we want an array of these.  But it's already an array, so you are now asking for an array of arrays of enum values: `UserTags[][]`.  Which would be `[["Fitness"], ["Fashion", "Foodie"]]`.

`keyof User["userTags"][]` means that we now want the keys of that array of arrays: `keyof UserTags[][]`.  The key of an array is a `number` so typescript gives you `number | keyof UserTags[][]`. (I'm not sure why it isn't *just* `number`).

---

Perhaps you were trying to get the keys for the `UserTags` enum object?  `keyof typeof UserTags` will give you the union type `"FITNESS" | "FOURTWENTY_FRIENDLY" | "MEDITATION" ...`.  But it doesn't seem like that's what you actually want to use.  You want the union of the enum values which is just `UserTags`.